# convert & to &amp; in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a variable containing XML value as

```
<xsl:variable name="resp">
<TABLE>
 <news_id>39</news_id>
 <news_title>Strada &#8211; TSO</news_title>
 <news_content>Extending the support to IFA&#8217;s family in form of income security by paying last drawn trail paid to IFA before the demise.</news_content>
 <news_type>1</news_type>
 <doc_url>upload/docs/12345.pdf</doc_url>
 <doc_size>185859</doc_size>
 <news_date>2014-09-19 12:54:11.0</news_date>
 <is_enabled>1</is_enabled>
</TABLE>  
<xsl:variable>
```

How to parse the values in this variable. Please help.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what result do you want to achieve?

Comment: Are you able to use XSLT 2.0 or are you limited to 1.0, and if the latter then which XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: You almost certainly don't *WANT* to convert the & to &amp;. Normal XML parsing will convert the numeric character references in this string to their corresponding Unicode characters; normal XML serialization will convert those characters back to their numeric character references.

Comment: @keshlam I certainly want 2 convert & to &amp; coz i hav no choice.I have a java file which returns:MOM–"Mission on Mars". if u observe the hyphen it's different 4m what we directly enter 4m keyboad i.e.,Keyboard hyphen is - & what DB returns is –. While sendin this output 4m XSLT, I was unable to read the hyphen. On searching, I found by including <xsl:output method="text" encoding="iso-8859-1"/>  in xslt, converts any special character into it's equivalent number encoding. So the number encoding for the hyphen is &#8211;. This will not be parsed in my java class until I convert & to &amp;.

Answer (score 0):

I you are to have the structure, you do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="resp">
            <TABLE>
                <news_id>39</news_id>
                <news_title>Strada &#8211; TSO</news_title>
                <news_content>Extending the support to IFA&#8217;s family in form of income security by paying last drawn trail paid to IFA before the demise.</news_content>
                <news_type>1</news_type>
                <doc_url>upload/docs/12345.pdf</doc_url>
                <doc_size>185859</doc_size>
                <news_date>2014-09-19 12:54:11.0</news_date>
                <is_enabled>1</is_enabled>
            </TABLE>  
        </xsl:variable>

        <!-- using copy-of to get the structure of the XML -->
        <xsl:copy-of select="$resp" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you want the text inside your variable, you do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="resp">
            <TABLE>
                <news_id>39</news_id>
                <news_title>Strada &#8211; TSO</news_title>
                <news_content>Extending the support to IFA&#8217;s family in form of income security by paying last drawn trail paid to IFA before the demise.</news_content>
                <news_type>1</news_type>
                <doc_url>upload/docs/12345.pdf</doc_url>
                <doc_size>185859</doc_size>
                <news_date>2014-09-19 12:54:11.0</news_date>
                <is_enabled>1</is_enabled>
            </TABLE>  
        </xsl:variable>
        <variable>
        <!-- using value-of to get the values of the XML inserting it into variable element -->
            <xsl:value-of select="$resp"/>
        </variable>


    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you want to get the different values from the elements inside the variable you do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="resp">
            <TABLE>
                <news_id>39</news_id>
                <news_title>Strada &#8211; TSO</news_title>
                <news_content>Extending the support to IFA&#8217;s family in form of income security by paying last drawn trail paid to IFA before the demise.</news_content>
                <news_type>1</news_type>
                <doc_url>upload/docs/12345.pdf</doc_url>
                <doc_size>185859</doc_size>
                <news_date>2014-09-19 12:54:11.0</news_date>
                <is_enabled>1</is_enabled>
            </TABLE>  
        </xsl:variable>

        <!-- If you want to get the value of news_id inside the variable you do this -->
        <newsId>
            <xsl:value-of select="$resp/TABLE/news_id"/>
        </newsId>

        <!-- Below is a shorter xpath-syntax -->
        <newsTitle>
            <xsl:value-of select="$resp//news_title"/>
        </newsTitle>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that navigating into the `$resp` variable with paths like `$resp/TABLE/news_id` will only work in an XSLT 2.0 processor.  For XSLT 1.0 you would have to use an extension function such as `exslt:node-set` to turn the result tree fragment in the variable into a proper node set.

Comment: &Trond : that was quick. Thank you. I need to navigate through resp in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: But are you receiving the XML as a variable, that is - you are receiving an XSLT-file, or do you store the whole structure as a variable?
What do you use to run XSLT? Language-vise that is.

Comment: I have a few java files which I am calling in my XSLT. One of the java files does the select operation returning few rows. This will be assigned to a variable which will now contain XML as I have given in the above example. The problem is I need to pass this result to another java file where it is failing due to some special characters. So, instead of passing to another java file to format the DB output,I am trying to format in XSLT. but again, I am unable to parse the XML data contained in the xsl variable.

Comment: &lan Robert : Since I am using XSLT 1.0, I tried with exsl. Still, I am unable to parse the output since the result contained in variable is still a string and not a tree. I need to convert to node-set if i have to pass this data to exsl:node-set($resp/TABLE/news_id) is not working.